# Wordpress article only shows first part of article

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

After changing my theme on my website, my articles do not show the hole article. it seems to only display the first part of the article and then it shows [...] I have changed the settings to display hole article. Am i missing another setting or is this a code error? 
You can view the website here [www.greywatershop.com.au][1]

```
  [1]: http://www.greywatershop.com.au/blog

Code for archives.php

    <?php
/**
 * The template for displaying archive pages
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
 *
 * @package Shopper
 */

get_header(); ?>

    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
            <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

            <header class="page-header">
                <?php
                    the_archive_title( '<h1 class="page-title">', '</h1>' );                    
                ?>
            </header><!-- .page-header -->

                <?php get_template_part( 'loop' );

            else :

            get_template_part( 'content', 'none' );

            endif; ?>

        </main><!-- #main -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php
do_action( 'shopper_sidebar' );
get_footer();
```

Comment: If your post your code from the archive.php file in your theme we could help you better. However it is likely that your theme is calling the post excerpt on the archive view or that it has a custom function to create that excerpt and therefore any options you might change from your admin panel will not apply.

Comment: So how would i fix this ?

Comment: Like I said, if you post your code I could probably help you better

Comment: sorry i misread your comment. I have edited added the code for archive.php above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not in the archives.php file, it is in the loop template.

In the template file, there should be a `the_excerpt();` function, replacing the function with `the_content();` will solve the problem.

`the_excerpt();` function will show part of the blog with an end of [...].

`the_content();` function will show the whole blog.

Comment: unfortunately i have tried to edit this and cant find it anywhere. there is no the_excerpt(); in functions.php, loop.php or any of the other files.

Comment: @TristanMichaelSmith you should check single.php file, which is the default template file for single posts.

Comment: So i ended up fixing it. it was not in the functions.php file it was in a function file created by the theme. so i have to change it in shopper-template-function.php and this worked.

Answer (score 1):

`the_excerpt()` is a core WordPress function, so you won't find it in y our themes function.php file. What you need to do is the following

1. If your theme has a single-blog.php file open it
2. If it doesent then open the single.php file
3. Look for the line of code were `the_excerpt()` is used
4. Replace that function with `the_content()`

That will show the full content of your post in the single view.